# React useEffect() localhost API fetching doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, api, localhost, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm having trouble with my ReactJS application. I'm trying to fetch data from an API that I've written (in GOlang) which is running on `localhost:9090`.

I'm trying to fetch data like this (setters takes 'TEST' for testing purpose)

```
function ImamsDetails() {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState(null);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:9090/imams/1')
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => {
                setFirstName('TEST');
                setLastName('TEST');
            });
        }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            Name: {!firstName || !lastName ? 'Loading...' : `${firstName} ${lastName}`}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 or my computer IP address, it doesn't work. It is stuck on "Loading...". Whereas, if I change the URI to a distant fake API like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 it works fine.

My API returns something like this :

```
{"Id":1,"FName":"XXX","LName":"YYY","PersonType":2,"GivenAudios":null}
```

which is the same format as the link posted below.

Any thought why it doesn't work with localhost?

Comment: can you try adding a `catch` and inspecting the error on `fetch`?

Comment: I have this message "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9090/imams/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: Ok, I've added the header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") on the response on the API and now it works fine, it was as stupid as that. Thank you for your help. How can I endorse you or something ?

Comment: Nah, just Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `create-react-app`? You should set up proxy in your `package.json` so you could fetch data from external urls. [Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) you can read more in React documentation.

Add this to your `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:9090"
```